# How to use get Android's acceleration with specified times?

Tags: android

I am a java newer,

I want to get, for example, 10 different values of my phone's acceleration,

and get an average value from them.

But I can only find answers for continued data, or only one data.

Now I can get one data and display it on my screen.

Can I use for loop to calculate for 10 times?

Thank you.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    aAngle = event.values[0];
    bAngle = event.values[1];
}

private Button.OnClickListener listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
switch(viewMode){
case VIEW_MODE_1:
title.setText(Double.toString(aAngle) + " " + Double.toString(bAngle));
            break;}
```

I've tried to cast a for loop in the OnSensorChanged method, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Try editing your post with some the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

onSensorChanged is fired everytime your sensor gets a new reading. you can place a counter for ten changes. keep track of values in a list,hashmap and aggregate them.

```
    public class SensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
         private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
         private final Sensor mAccelerometer;
private int count=0;
private List<String> eventX=new ArrayList<String>();


         public SensorActivity() {
             mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
             mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
         }

         protected void onResume() {
             super.onResume();
             mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
         }

         protected void onPause() {
             super.onPause();
             mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
         }

         public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
         }

         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
eventX.add(event.getValueMethodwhateverItis());
count++;
if (count=10){
//aggregate from list do anything you want.;
}
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this, but it seems to have a runtime error.

```
List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (sensors.size() > 0 && sensors.size() <= 10) {
sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensors.get(count),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); 
count ++;
}
```

also, I create two list to save the result every time when my angle is changed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < aAngleList.size(); i++){
        double aAngleTotal = 0;
        double bAngleTotal = 0;
        aAngleTotal += aAngleList.get(i);
        bAngleTotal += bAngleList.get(i);
        aAngleAverage = aAngleTotal / aAngleList.size();
        bAngleAverage = bAngleTotal / bAngleList.size();
    }

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    aAngleList.add(aAngle);
    bAngleList.add(bAngle);
}
```

the for loop is in onResume, right under the if  (sensors...)